# Anagrams and related problems

Tags: combinatorics

I have a word like CONSTITUTIONALIST that is very fun for Anagram problems.
So, in order to count the anagrams I have to:
\begin{align*}
s=\left\{C(2),O(2),N(2),S(2),T(3),I(3),A(1)\right\}\\
P_{17!}^{2,2,2,2,3,3,1} = \dfrac{17!}{2!2!2!2!3!3!2!1!}
\end{align*}

Is that correct?

So, if I wish to find out how many anagrams exists that have have no consecutive vowels repeated like, AA,EE...What would be the better way o solve?

And if I would like to find out how many anagrams the I (that appears 3 times) never appear together 2 times ("II" may not occur).  What would be the simplest way to solve?

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your count of the letters, but you have the right method to find the number of anagrams.

Comment: For no two $I$ in a row, which I assume includes $3$, imagine writing $14$ X's like this: X X X $\dots$ X X. That gives $15$ "gaps" (including endgaps). The $3$ places where $I$ goes can be chosen in $\binom{15}{3}$ ways. Deal with the other letters as before.

Comment: Caution -- it's Stilton! Auction it on stilts!

Comment: The repetition of vowels are not exclusive to repeated equal vowels like II, EE or AA.  It is any sequence of vowels.  That is my pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** Let $a$ be the total amount of anagrams. Now if we want to count $a_{OO},$ the total amount of anagrams that have two consecutive "O", we may consider "OO" as a "new letter" and recount the total amount of anagrams (with one letter less and one different letter). Then there are exactly $a-a_{OO}$ anagrams that don't contains two consecutive $O$. Now, if we want to consider the number of anagrams that do not contain two consecutive "I", it is a little bit more tricky because there are three "I" to place. If we create a new letter "II" and count the number of anagram with it, then we will also count anagrams containing "II""I", so that $a-a_{II}$ is not equal to number of anagram without two consecutive "I". This is why you also have to count the number $a_{III}$ of anagrams with "III", so that the total number of anagrams without two consecutive "I" is given by $a-a_{II}-a_{III}$. Etc.

Comment: So, by doing that and knowing I have 7 occurences of vowels I must do $C_{7,2}$ for any 2 vowels coming together?
- And how to avoid the repetitions?
- And how to avoid situations like CVVCVVC... ?
he problem is the understand the logic of thought behind the exermple.